Fourier-like transforms for a Day convolution?
The presheaf category on a monoidal category inherits the monoidal structure via the Day convolution. Moreover you can inherit (bi)closed monoidal structure.
In the study of Fourier analysis we can use the Fourier transform $F$ and its inverse as tools of simplification. That is, we have two sorts of tensor products: convolution of functions $\otimes_{hard}$ , and multiplication of functions $\otimes_{easy}$. From here we can simplify hard calculations as easy ones:
$$A \otimes_{hard} B = F^{-1} ( FA \otimes_{easy} FB)$$
Abstracting over this principle I find myself asking a few questions:

Can the Fourier transform be nicely categorified in a useful manner such that is groks with the Day convolution?
For presheaf categories $P$ that carry a convolutional monoidal structure, what other sorts of categorical structure do we need to model a Fourier-like approach? I'm loosely referring to a Fourier-like transform as one which "turns convolution into multiplication" in a way that is advantageous/"easier".

Apologies that these are loose questions. A cursory search online doesn't find much for 1, and finds nothing for 2.
I have some vague ideas on 2. To model the Fourier transform, you could have a (strong? lax?) monoidal functor $F$ out of $P$ into some other category with a computationally easier tensor. Perhaps $F$ should form either an isomorphism or equivalence of categories so that this transform is invertible.
However, each of these hunches don't feel too principled and I find myself naively categorifying the existing approach without much insight. So I am here asking for some more resources that may have touched on this idea, suggestions on why such a thing might not be useful/interesting, or some ideas on a principled way to structure such a construction

You may want to look at the lecture by J. Lurie on The Categorification of fourier theory https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3f8KEcv4RE

The equation is the essence of the definition of a monoidal functor, which, like the Fourier transform in reality, need not be an equivalence.  Then you might search for the various ways in which differentiation and integration can be modelled in category theory.

I think Fosco has a section (5.5.1) on his book precisely about this!
